# In Laravel how do i filter string on reuqest object for all inputs in middleware?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-injection, middleware

Let me explain in details

I want to protect my query string variable for Injection String

URL: [http://domainname.com/report?start_date=';](http://domainname.com/report?start_date=%27;) SELECT; --

Like as you see in above URL there some unexpected string and i want to trim that while getting that on controller using $request object

Ex: $start_date = $request->get('start_date');

And then i am using this $start_date directly to the query
I don't want to use validator on that how could i do that using middle-ware for all inputs (not specific to only start_date)
Fetch all inputs and strip tags and remove special characters

Comment: you should be using prepared statements to do your queries in the first place ... you should never be directly putting user input into a raw query

Comment: @lagbox It's laravel and it already use PDO but even i don't want that to be reached on that statement

Comment: Do I get it right that you want to remove a literal `'; SELECT; --` substring from all inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have Middlware called TrimStrings it's normally located at

```
/app/Http/Middlware/TrimStrings.php
```

After that you can overwrite the function `transform` so it looks like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings as Middleware;

class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];
    
    protected function transform($key, $value)
    {
        $value = htmlentities($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        $value = $this->myCustomFilteringFunction(); // You can add your function and to whatever you want
        
        if (in_array($key, $this->except, true)) {
            return $value;
        }

        return is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
    }
}
```

There is no need to reinvent the wheel this middleware method `transform` will be called on every field. So everything is being taken care of. Just add your filtering rules.

Comment: Why ? The OP wants solution someone already told him that doing that is wrong. But this is what he wants or i am mistaken ?

Comment: @PetyoTsonev look like this will work for me.. Let me test that with my requirements

Comment: Crippling inputs is always a bad idea. Suppose In one field I am sending my height which is `5'6"` which your function will transform into an incomprehensible monster  `5'6&amp;quot;`.

Comment: That's why there is except property where you can disable this check on inputs you don't need. Isn't that right ? I am against that approach and i would never do it myself. But the OP needs help on that this is his requirement and we help him. As I said i think he already knows that this is not good practice.

Comment: *I would't be so sure* that the OP already knows that this is not a good practice.

Comment: You can check the first comment of his post. Anyway... Let's not to get into controversy, what he knows and what he don't is totally up to him. Who are we to judge...